# ImageMagick gradient ratio

Tags: imagemagick, gradient, linear-gradients

How do I adjust the color ratio of a gradient?

I currently use the following to create my gradient.

```
convert -size 200x600 gradient:none-black output.png
```

[image: default]

[image: adjusted]

Comment: Please explain what you mean by color ratio? You can specify colors by rgb() values or gray() values or hex values or hsb() value. See https://imagemagick.org/script/color.php

Comment: @fmw42 The ratio at which the color starts and stops. I assume that the default is 50% - 50% between none and black. I would like to adjust this ratio to 60% - 40%

Comment: I am sorry, I still do not understand. Percent of what? Can you provide an example image showing what you want?

Comment: @fmw42 thanks for your help, I've posted screen-grabs that will help explain what I mean by color ratio.

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: Please post the same gradients from red to blue. They will be easier to analyze. What tool made them and what were the commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want this, where you get to the half-red/half-blue colour just 20% of the way down the height of the image. It is done by creating two gradients of different lengths and putting them back-to-back:

```
midcolour="rgb(127,0,127)"
convert -size 100x20 gradient:red-"$midcolour"  \
        -size 100x80 gradient:"$midcolour"-blue \
        -append result.png
```

[image]

Another way is to put 3 single pixels together in a row and then resize that up to what you want. I know you want the middle to be 40% red and 60% blue, but, for ease of viewing, I'll make it lime green:

```
convert -size 1x1 xc:red xc:lime xc:blue -append -resize 100x100\! result.png
```

[image]

You would change `lime` to something like "rgb(100,0,155)".

Comment: Nice. I think the first one is what he wants.

Answer (score 3):

Although at least one acceptable solution has been provided, here are a couple other ideas...

Example 1: This command creates a red-blue gradient of the finished dimensions, crops it into a top and bottom half, resizes them to 40 and 60 percent of the input height, and appends them back to make a single image. What started as the color at the exact vertical center is now at 40% down from the top with clean gradients going up and down from there.

```
convert -size 200x600 gradient:red-blue -crop 1x2@ \
   \( -clone 0 -resize 100x40% \) \( -clone 1 -resize 100x60% \) \
   -delete 0,1 -append result.png
```

That splits the gradient image into a top and bottom half, then inside parentheses it resizes each to the required proportion. After that it deletes the 50/50 crops from before the parentheses, appends the two resized remaining images, and writes the output.

Example 2: This next example starts by creating the red-blue gradient in the final dimensions, then sets variables to hold the top color, the exact middle color, and the bottom color.

Then inside the first parentheses it clones and crops the image to 60% its original height. It uses "-sparse-color" to fill that with a gradient from "color1" to "color2".

Inside the second parentheses it clones and crops the image to 40% its original height, and using "-sparse-color" again it fills it with a gradient from "color2" to "color3".

After creating those two gradients, delete the original, append the other two together, and write the output.

```
convert -size 200x600 gradient:red-blue \
   -set option:color1 "%[pixel:p{0,0}]" \
   -set option:color2 "%[pixel:p{0,h/2}]" \
   -set option:color3 "%[pixel:p{0,h}]" \
   \( -clone 0 -extent 100x60% \
      -sparse-color barycentric "0,0 %[color1] 0,%[h] %[color2]" \) \
   \( -clone 0 -extent 100x40% \
      -sparse-color barycentric "0,0 %[color2] 0,%[h] %[color3]" \) \
   -delete 0 -append result.png
```

Comment: Nice approaches!

Comment: @GeeMack I do like your first example 1. I'll keep it in mind in future.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I understand. But if you want to start with 90% transparent (10% opaque black) and end with black. You can do:

```
convert -size 200x600 gradient:"graya(0,0.1)-black" output.png
```

graya means gray with alpha. So graya(0,0.1) is gray(0) or black with 0.1 fraction opacity, so 90% transparent.

Perhaps this is what you want:

Normal 50-50:

```
convert -size 200x600 gradient:red-blue red_blue1.png
```

[image]

60-40:

```
rr=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:0.6*255]" info:`
bb=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:0.4*255]" info:`
convert -size 200x600 gradient:"rgb($rr,0,$bb)-rgb(0,0,255)" red_blue2.png
```

[image]

Or perhaps this is what you want:

```
bb=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:0.1*255]" info:`
convert -size 200x600 gradient:"rgb(255,0,$bb)-rgb(0,0,255)" red_blue3.png
```

[image]

Comment: I think OP is happy to go from 100% black to 100% red, but doesn't want the midpoint (in colour terms) of that range at the midpoint (in geometric terms) of his image. I think. He kind of wants to get to 50% red at 40% of the way down his image.

Comment: Yes, I thought that might be the case. But Imagemagick gradients do not work that way. You can only give it end colors. So one has to figure out the end color that will bias the midline as desired. I proposed one method, but I am not sure it is the correct formulation.

Answer (score 0):

I have an Imagemagick bash shell script called, multigradient, which may do what you want. It allows you to create gradients of many colors each with stops to set where they start. For example:

```
multigradient -w 200 -h 600 -s "blue 0 red 80" -d to-top result.png
```

The first color must start at 0, but the direction can be many options. Here I go from bottom to top with pure blue at the bottom and pure red starting at 80 up from the bottom going to the top

[image]

([See](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick))